# sklearn lda gridsearchcv with pipeline

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

```
pipe = Pipeline([('reduce_dim', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()),('classify', LogisticRegression())])
param_grid = [{'classify__penalty': ['l1', 'l2'],
                 'classify__C': [0.05,0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0]}] 

gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=3)
gs.fit(data, label)
```

I have a question for using pipeline and  gridsearchcv. now i first try to use lda to reduce dimension, i want to know the process about gridsearchcv with pipeline ?
split train/test->lda->fit & predict or lda->split train/test->fit & predict?

Comment: The first option is viable for a real world scenario. Because in second one, the LDA will have information leak from the test data. Anyways this question is less about programming and more about the methodology and hence suitable for [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: After @sera 's comment, I also want to be clear if you want the order in which the gridSearchCV works, or do you want to know which order is more suitable for the task.

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

First of all, the `Pipeline` defines the steps that you are going to do.

In your case, first you use `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` and then `LogisticRegression`.

**Part 2**

In

```
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=3)
```

you have defined cross validation (cv) = 5.

This number defines **the number of folds** ((Stratified)KFold) so you split your data automatically 5 times into train and test data and every single time you perform the analysis that `Pipeline` defines.

Bottom line: the first case (split train/test->lda->fit & predict) seems better but the question is methodology-related.